# Memory requirements for FFT on STM32F103C8

Tags: fft, stm32

I have a limited system and would like to implement FFT within STM32F103C8 without any extra memory buffers.

So I want to know how many memories are needed to implement if I have 2592x1944x8bit size's one image?

Actually, I want to have a process such as

Origial image ---> FFT ---> Blur ---> IFFT ---> Modified image

What is the memory requirements for FFT on STM32F103C8 ?

Comment: Might be better asked at https://dsp.stackexchange.com/ . What are the parameters of the blur? Are you sure going into the frequency domain is the best way to do it?

Comment: @ZalmanStern Actually the blur(Gaussian) size is quite a bit huge size. 60x60~90x90 variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So I want to know how many memories are needed to implement if I have 2592x1944x8bit size's one image?

Much more than you have. This isn't going to work out.

2592x1944 @ 8bpp is roughly 5 MB. Your microcontroller has 20 KB of RAM, which isn't even enough to store eight lines of your image.